# How to retrieve "selected Item ID" from Unselected ListBox of a "Multilist With Search" Field?

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8

Please find the image below.Thanks in Advance.

[image]

Comment: Where are you trying to retrieve it from? server side? JavaScript? Need more information to be able to answer your question

Comment: Hi @Richard,well.I want to retrieve it from server side.

Answer (score 0):

You can read the selected values of "Multilist With Search" field as following:

```
Sitecore.Data.Fields.MultilistField _multilistField = Sitecore.Context.Item.Fields["fieldname"];
if (_multilistField != null)
{
  foreach (ID _id in _multilistField.TargetIDs)
  {
    Item yourSelectedItem = Sitecore.Context.Database.Items[_id];
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi syam,well thanks for support.how ever,I want to retrieve item from unselected list box.

Comment: I don't think there is a direct way to do that. You need to do some logic like getting the selected items and the items in your list data source and then using a LINQ query to exclude the selected items. hope this help.

Comment: Would you like to look into it,please.

Comment: Highlighted=Sitecore.Context.ClientPage.ClientRequest.Form[HighlightedControl];

Comment: public string HighlightedControl
        {
            get { return ClientID + "_highlighted"; }
        }  public string Highlighted
        {
            get { return Sitecore.StringUtil.GetString(ServerProperties["Highlighted"]); }
            set { ServerProperties["Highlighted"] = value; }
        }

Comment: hope,this above will help you for more sharp and clean answer. I am getting a bit error ,please guide me.